# Receiving no translated text from an https request to translate.google.com

Tags: https, lua, request, google-translate, roblox

Now I tried to make like a translator through Roblox Studio using Https service by sending a request to the translate.google.com link the thing is that anything I get in return does not give me the translated text.

I put what I received in a google doc and tried to find it by pressing ctrl + f to try to find it but no luck the only thing I could find is that text that was supposed to be translated. Here is the code in case you want to try it for yourself but I do warn you that running this might make Roblox unresponsive for a while since it is a lot of info they gave back.

I don't know if I am doing something wrong or not someone please help! I just want it to give me what 'Hello world' would be in french, there are also no error messages.

```lua
local http = game:GetService("HttpService")

local Message = "Hello world"

http:UrlEncode(Message) -- 'Hello world' -> 'Hello%20world'

local response = http:RequestAsync(
    {
        Url = "https://translate.google.com/?sl=en&tl=fr&text=" .. Message .. "!&op=translate";
        Method = "GET"
    }
    )

if response.Success then
    print(response.StatusMessage)
    print(response.StatusCode)
    print(response.Body)
    --print(response.Headers)
else
    print("The request failed: ", response.StatusCode, response.StatusMessage)
end
```

Comment: Please provide us the logged value of `response` after the request and the request logs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When visiting on your browser (for example) the url `https://translate.google.com/?sl=en&tl=fr&text=Hello%20World!&op=translate`, the translation you see is fetched using Javascript code executed by the browser after loading the page.

The browser retrieves the html body of the page (like you did in your code) and then executes the javascript in the html body which retrieves the translation and updates the page.

Unless you use a browser driver like Selenium I don't see how you can do what you want in a simple way.

Plus, I'm sure that Google has some protection against automatic bots, so after too many request your program will probably will be blocked by ReCaptcha.

The correct way to translate the text is to use the [Google Cloud Translate API](https://cloud.google.com/translate) which I think is [free up to 500k requests per month](https://cloud.google.com/translate/pricing). There is also [Azure Translator](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cognitive-services/translator/#pricing) from Microsoft which also has a free tier.

Comment: Didn't know there was an translate api from google really helpful ty much love

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is likely in how you are URL Encoding the string.

```
http:UrlEncode(Message)
```

[HttpService.UrlEncode](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/HttpService/UrlEncode) returns the encoded string as a new value. It doesn't mutate the existing value. So you just need to store the result of the function call.

```
Message = http:UrlEncode(Message)
```

EDIT : Just as @Mohamed AMAZIRH pointed out, hitting this URL will only return HTML.

Comment: Forgot about that ty for pointing it out much love